# Salesforce chrome extension not showing up Sandbox and Production options

Tags: integration, gmail

There is a chrome extension to tag emails from Gmail to Salesforce records which requires logging into salesforce from Gmail. To login to sandbox, the extension's options needs to be captured to Sandbox and respective for production if they want to use production to log details.
But it is not showing any options as below.

[image]

Comment: I have the plugin and use it for work. I see the same behavior in the options box. Try to reinstall it and see if during initial config you can select sandbox. Otherwise, you will likely have to contact Salesforce about this issue (Salesforce is the publisher for the extension).

Comment: @GlenDeMarcos  I have tried reinstalling it multiple times. Still facing this issue. I'll try to contact Salesforce regarding this issue. So what was the solution you followed for this problem?

Comment: I'm exclusively using it for a prod instance and haven't had the need to use it with a sandbox. Otherwise I would have followed your same steps. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I was able to fix it by pressing the letter "S". Give it a try.